# Integrate SSRS with web app

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have developed a web app using javascript , node/express server and an sql-server database and we want to integrate an SSRS server on it .

I have created a report server ,connected it to the app's sql-server db , and created some random reports .

We want to integrate the SSRS server on the front-end of our app and print reports .

Is there any API , or add-on to use to embed the report server in the web app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can embed the report server. But you can embed directly the reports.

To do that you have two differents methods one for all reports and the other only for paginate report :

1. Iframe :

You juste have to add `?rs:Embed=true` at the end of the src's Url in your iframe.

2. C#, ReportViewer / ServerReport

You can also use [ReportViewer and ServerReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-webforms-reportviewer-control) to embed paginate report. You must use a WebForm app.

First put that in the top of your code :

`<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>`

And after you can put this where you want in your page.

`<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="PATH" ReportServerUrl="URL"/>
 </rsweb:ReportViewer>`

Comment: I prefer the second way. If you are sending parameters in the URL, it's easy to change those and gain access to data you shouldn't have.